# Get user-defined class attributes from class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

How to get user-defined class attributes from class instance? I tried this:

```
class A:
    FOO = 'foo'
    BAR = 'bar'

a = A()

print(a.__dict__)  # {}
print(vars(a))  # {}
```

I use python 3.5.
Is there a way to get them?
I know that `dir(a)` returns a list with names of attributes, but I need only used defined, and as a dict name to value.

Answer (score 7):

You've defined those variables within the class namespace which haven't propagated into instances. You can use the `__class__` attribute of the instance to access the class object, and then use the `__dict__` method to get the namespace's contents:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in a.__class__.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith('__')}
{'BAR': 'bar', 'FOO': 'foo'}
```

Comment: I forget to mention that it should also return attributes from parents

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [5]: [x for x in dir(a) if not x.startswith('__')]
Out[5]: ['BAR', 'FOO']
```